# Can't launch bluetooth file browser due to missing "obex_thunar.sh" file

Tags: bluetooth, thunar

On my Dell Studio 1550 laptop: I have Xubuntu installed. I succesfully paired the device. Now when I click on "Browse files on device" I get this message:

```
Failed to launch "obex_thunar.sh"
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
You can enter an alternate browser in service settings
```

On my friends laptop (latest Ubuntu installed and up to date), when you click "Browse files on device" actually nothing happens...

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

The file manager seems to want to launch a file called "obex_thunar.sh", which isn't provided by any package in Ubuntu.

The closest reference to a file like this is from this wiki page:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth

You can probably just make a script called that like that wiki page and see if it works.

Comment: I just don't get this! I created obex_thunar.sh file put it into /usr/bin and chmod +x. It's all the same except the error message is a little different......

[Errno 8] Exec format error ... you can enter an alternate browser in service settings ..... I HATE THIS!